# PostgreSQL - Does doing analyze have the same performance cost as count(*)?

Tags: postgresql

To start off, I want to do an estimated count of how large a table is. Since I am building an analytical data of the database using graphs, exact count is not important. Thus I came across this [wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting) and it suggested doing an estimated count using

```
SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'table_name';
```

Now in order to get an updated count, we would have to do an `analyze` on that table.

So my question is that is using `analyze` to get an updated count of the `reltuples` the same thing as doing `count(*)`? Is there a performance hit on doing `analyze` as much as doing `count(*)`?

Answer (score 1):

The cost of running analyze depends on how much of the table is sampled, which depends on the default_statistics_target or the per-column statistics setting.  It could be either faster or slower than count(*) depending on your specifics--there is not replacement for actually trying and seeing on your own system with our own data.

But normally if you are happy with an estimate, you would just use the reltuples you find there already.  re-analyzing the table each time would seem to defeat the purpose.